# What is $\sqrt{-36}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I am working on a math problem $(x^{2} - 6x + 45)$  where I must utilize the "completing the square" method, and was able to break down the problem to $(x-3)^{2} = -36.$

I know I have to take the square roots of both sides getting $x-3$ on the left, but for the right, I know 6 is one of the roots for the square root of -36 but what would be the other?  Initially, I thought it would be 6i but that is wrong. What is the other root?

Comment: 6 is **not** a square root of -36.

Comment: 6i is one of them. 6 is not.

Comment: @Nij I'm not going to argue against you but the portal where I am doing these questions states that 6 is.

Comment: @ian I believe you, really I do but the portal that's taking these answers states that it is....idk why

Comment: That portal is wrong, and you can verify it directly, $6^2=36 \neq -36$.

Comment: @ian so if 6i is one, then what is the other?

Comment: The other one is $-6i$ if you are considering complex solutions.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks, I was thinking that (or overthinking). I just learned about how I and I^2 translate to sqrt of -1 and -1. So I was confusing myself

Comment: יהודה - since you are just learning about it, I'll mention that it should always be lower case, $i$, never I.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC But note, if you use Mathematica it must be capital I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. \begin{align}&&x^2&=9\\ &\iff&\sqrt{x^2}&=\sqrt9\\ &\iff&|x|&=3\\ &\iff& x&=\pm3\end{align}

   Notice that the radical sign $\sqrt{\;\;}$ gives just the principal
   square root; so, $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|\not\equiv x.$ Presumably, this (applying
   the square root function) is what you mean when you say "to take
   square root of both sides".

   However, dealing with complex numbers, the definition of "principal
   root" is arguable: for example, does the principal third root
   $\sqrt[3] {-1}\;$ of $-1$ equal $$-1\;\text{(real)}$$ or
   $$\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i=e^{i \frac\pi3}\;\text{(smallest
   nonnegative argument)}?$$ In the complex world, the convention may
   still be that the radical sign outputs just the principal root, so
   it's a good idea to avoid using the symbol $\sqrt[n]{\;\;}$ there.
2. Just as $$x^2=9\iff x=\pm\sqrt9\:=\pm3,$$ we also have that
   \begin{align}&&(x-3)^{2} &= -36 \\&\iff &x-3&=\pm6i \\&\iff &x&=3\pm6i.\end{align}
3. **This is incorrect**: \begin{align}&&(x-3)^{2} &= -36 \\&\iff& x-3 &= \sqrt{-36}.\end{align}

   This is correct: \begin{align}&&(x-3)^{2} &= -36 \\&\iff&
   \text{principal square root of }(x-3)^2 &= \sqrt{-36} \\&&&=
   6i\\&\iff&x-3&=\pm6i.\end{align}
4. Also, notice that the various $n$th roots of a number cannot
   generally be generated from its principal $n$th root by merely
   adding a $\pm$ in front: \begin{align}&&(x-3)^{3} &= -36 \iff x-3
   =-3.30,1.65\pm2.86i.\end{align}